# Get data from local entries XML in WSO2

Tags: wso2-esb

I have local-entries XML file as below:-

```
<localEntry key="LocalEntryProxy" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<list>
    <First>
        <A>value1</A>
        <B>value2</B>
        <C>value3</C>
    </First>
    <Second>
        <A>value4</A>
        <B>value5</B>
        <C>value6</C>
    </Second>
</list>
```

Now I am trying to get the value of elemnt "A" which is inside "Second", i.e value4. My code is below:-

```
<property expression="get-property('registry','conf:/CollectionTest/LocalEntryProxy.xml')" name="LocalFile" scope="default" type="OM"/>
<log description="LOGProp" level="custom">
            <property expression="$ctx:LocalFile//*[local-name()='A']" name="getA"/>
</log>
```

But I am getting both as output:- "value1value4". Can someone tell how to get "value4", what change should be made in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpath expression is wrong that is the reason you are getting both the values of A.
Try below expression

```
$ctx:LocalFile//*[local-name()='Second']/*[local-name()='A']
```